# Unreliable data Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, store, getter, mutation

I am trying to use Vuex and am having trouble to understand why my data is not the expected value.

What I am trying to do is pass the result of a getter to a mutation commit as follows

```
// TEST PRINT: return value of getter
console.log(this.$store.getters.reservationsCurrentWeek);
        
switch (this.activeCalendar) {
  case 'week':
   // Commit with getter result
   this.$store.commit('setShownReservations', this.$store.getters.reservationsCurrentWeek);
   break;
```

The first print shows the expected result.
However when I print what value is actually passed inside the mutation as follows:

```
// TEST PRINT: return value of getter
console.log(this.getters.reservationsCurrentWeek);
      
// TEST PRINT: parameter passed to the mutation.
console.log(value);
      
state.shownReservations = value;
```

The parameter value is is not what the getter returned (but some old value). When I access the getter directly in my mutation it also gives a correct value. I don't get why I can't pass the result of the the getter as a parameter to a mutation commit and why it produces an unreliable value?

Answer (score 0):

From where are you trying to access `this.getters.reservationsCurrentWeek` ? If you are accessing getters from mutation and getters and mutations placed in one file you can use

```
mutations: {
  YOUR_MUTATION(state, {data, getters}) {
    console.log(getters);
  }
}
```

and then access getters. Or import getters from another file if it placed in separate file.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It works but gives another problem that the filter function I use in my getter is called on undefined even though I initialized the state `state: { reservations: {} }`. Nevertheless, is it good practice to call a getter from a component or inside the mutation? And I still don't get why getting the getter' s computed value in my component en then pass it to the mutation as data does not work. Or at least why result has changed when passed as a data parameter.

Comment: The whole reason I am using mutations and not actions is because of synchronicity not wanting inconsistency. Just synchronously setting and getting state. But now my application seems to have unexpected behavior.  Not knowing whether it is my understanding or implementation that is lacking.